# C++ Is it possible to return a reference to a private object and preventing change?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm needing to return a reference to a private member of a Class I wrote. I'm doing it like this:

In MyClass2.h I have the following line

```
MyClass* getObj(){return &instance_myclass;}
```

I will make sure that my code does not change any value of instance_myclass. But just to make sure, is there a way to return this reference read only, so that I can't change its value? Or is this, by the definition, not possible?

Answer (score 5):

You do not currently return a reference but a **pointer**.

In order to return a **reference**, use:

```
MyClass& getObj() { return instance_myclass; }
```

If you want to prevent modifications via that reference, just make it `const` (and while you're at it, make the function `const` as well):

```
MyClass const& getObj() const { return instance_myclass; }
```

Comment: And make that method `const` too :)

Comment: Note that while making the method `const` is a good idea. It's not that it would help in hindering modification of the member - it's rather that you can call the method if the object itself is const declared.

Comment: I've been reading because I honestly thought that reference and pointer were the same thing. Just to be clear instance_myclass is a pretty large data structure and I want to avoid copying it, while simply reading it. By returning a reference, I don't generate a copy of the variable right?

Comment: @aarelovich: Pointers and references are very different things. Please read up on them in your book. Generally, you should not be afraid of returning large data structures by value; it's less error-prone and highly optimised, especially if you use standard-library containers.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll keep your recomendation in consideration.

Comment: @aarelovich When receiving reference values make sure you use a reference type in lvalue. As it is one of the common beginners pit-falls. Example - MyClass &refObj = getObj(); And not MyClass obj = getObj(); The second call will invoke the copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had done this: MyClass data; if (condition) data = anotherclass.getObj1(); else data = anotherclass.getObj2();  This is why I wanted this. I need to do the exact same algorithm on two identical structures depending on a condition and I did not want to copy and paste the code for one and change the names. So I thought of returning a reference/pointer in order to not copy the data structures themselves....